# Customer Purchase Quantity Grid

Tags: customer, grid, magento-1.9

http://www.workwearexpress.com/bundle-deals/uc124-50/382

The above link shows a site which has a grid so customers can order garments I am trying to recreate this but trying to find is it an extension or something in Magento I haven't used yet. Any tips would be grateful

Comment: Hi Marius at this stage I am seeing if to achieve this I need an addon or I can do with in magento but needing some pointers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the link is dead and without it the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago we have done exactly what you need ... today !

We start from a magento grouped product and modified the layout of the product page
in order to show the grid base the product attribute "color" in row and "size" for
the columns.

pleas ask if you need more info.